# jquery form select (if exists in $_POST)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select

I'm trying to redo this in jQuery:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var thisIsSelected = '<?php echo $_POST['image']; ?>';
  var sel1= document.getElementById('image');
  sel1.value = thisIsSelected;
</script>
```

But I seem to keep breaking it lol

Basically I want jQuery to check if $_POST['image'] exists and if so make it selected on the form. I'm assuming if it's possibly with javascript, jquery can do it easier ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in jQuery, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#image').val("<?php echo $_POST['image']; ?>");
});
```

The `$(function() { });` wrap is so the code executes on `document.ready`, when all the elements are there and ready.  If the value doesn't exist in the `<option>` list, the `.val()` will just have no effect.